# + signs appearing in console in R

Tags: r

I´m  quite new at programming, and I started with R. I wanted to make a script which takes as input a matrix with the columns: time, x, y (coordenates) and then divide the time spent in each quadrant of a circular area. I have a roughly done script, but for any reason I don´t understand, when I execute the for loop in the editor, it appears all the letters red in the console with a "+" at the beginning of each line, which doesn´t let me open any other object any more when I call it.

```
set.seed(20)
x = matrix(rnorm(10,3,4),10,1)
y = matrix (rnorm(10,3,4),10,1)
time = matrix (1:10,10,1)
a = cbind (time,x,y)
colnames(a) = c("time","x","y")


  upperright =  a[,2] > 0 && a[,3] > 0 
  upperleft =   a[,2] < 0 && a[,3] > 0
  lowerright =  a[,2] > 0 && a[,3] < 0
  lowerleft =   a[,2] < 0 && a[,3] < 0

calculation <- function () {
    upperrightquadrant = 0
    upperleftquadrant = 0
    lowerrightquadrant = 0
    lowerleftquadrant = 0
for (i in c(1:nrow(a))){
    if (upperright) upperrightquadrant <<- sum((a[i,1]-a[i-1,1]))
    if (upperleft)upperleftquadrant <<- sum((a[i,1]-a[i-1,1]))
    if (lowerright) lowerrightquadrant <<-sum((a[i,1]-a[i-1,1]))
    if (lowerleft) lowerleftquadrant <<- sum((a[i,1]-a[i-1,1]))
}}
output = lapply (a, calculation)
```

Comment: Not quite clear on your question, but FWIW you can get rid of this by executing `options(continue="  ")`, for example, when you start a new session.

Comment: my guess (without looking closely) is that you have forgotten to close a parenthesis or a quote somewhere.  A programming editor with syntax highlighting and bracket-matching can help discover where.  Depending on your platform/editor, ESC/Ctrl-C/"Stop" button can get you unstuck.

Comment: PS this executes for me as written, except that I get the error `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (X[[1]])` at the end.

Comment: same as @BenBolker --- error `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (X[[1]])`

Comment: Sorry I may have not used the right terms (Just starting). What I meant is that the code works fine until I get to the function with the for loop. When I press the Crl+R with the calculation function it appears in the console with the + signs and then when I want see again another variable that worked before (eg. a), now I´m not able to get the matrix displayed anymore. I guess I´m doing something wrong with the brackets in the for loop and thus appears the + signs in the console but I´m not able to figure it out.After options(continue="+") I can call variable "a" but not function calculation

Comment: From what I see from your two last comments, if it works for you executing the calculation function then it shouldn´t be a mistake in the code rather than something in my console/workspace/whatever, any ideas??  The other error you report is the next step (which you are welcome to help :))

Comment: One problem you're having is that your function `calculation` takes no arguments, yet when you use it in `lapply` it will be passed a column of the data.frame. (I'm getting "unused argument" when I run your code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` symbols are only a way to show that the current statement is conitnuation of the previous lines's statement. That's perfectly OK. There are a couple of other problems with your program which are stopping it from producing your intended result. If I have in fact, understood what you are trying to do, I have added a possible solution at the end. First, let me suggest the edits and the reason for them:

1. `&` should have been used instead of `&&`. `&` is the vectorized operator. So, `upperright =  a[,2] > 0 & a[,3] > 0` instead of `upperright =  a[,2] > 0 && a[,3] > 0`.
2. You are passing a value to the function so its definition should include the parameter `calculation <- function (a)` instead of `calculation <- function ()`.
3. upperright, upperleft, ... are vectors and you should check individual elements instead of the whole vector `if (upperright[i])` instead of `if (upperright)`.
4. Problem with `sum((a[i,1]-a[i-1,1]))` at i==1, i-1 equals 0. If you are only counting, incrementing the count by 1 should be sufficient.
5. The objects upperrightquadrant, upperleftquadrant, ... are in your function environment only. So, no  need for `<<-`.
6. Finally, as you have already written the `for` loop to iterate over your matrix rowwise, no need for lapply or other similar looping functions.

   Only a suggestion: Use `<-` operator for assignments instead of `=`.

Now, the corrected program:

```
set.seed(20)
x = matrix(rnorm(10,3,4),10,1)
y = matrix (rnorm(10,3,4),10,1)
time = matrix (1:10,10,1)
a = cbind (time,x,y)

colnames(a) = c("time","x","y")

upperright =  a[,2] > 0 & a[,3] > 0 
upperleft =   a[,2] < 0 & a[,3] > 0
lowerright =  a[,2] > 0 & a[,3] < 0
lowerleft =   a[,2] < 0 & a[,3] < 0

calculation <- function (a) {
  upperrightquadrant = 0
  upperleftquadrant = 0
  lowerrightquadrant = 0
  lowerleftquadrant = 0
  for (i in c(1:nrow(a))){
    if (upperright[i]) upperrightquadrant <- upperrightquadrant + 1
    if (upperleft[i]) upperleftquadrant <- upperleftquadrant + 1
    if (lowerright[i]) lowerrightquadrant <- lowerrightquadrant + 1
    if (lowerleft[i]) lowerleftquadrant <- lowerleftquadrant + 1
  }

  list(upperrightquadrant = upperrightquadrant, upperleftquadrant = upperleftquadrant,
       lowerrightquadrant = lowerrightquadrant, lowerleftquadrant = lowerleftquadrant)
}
output = calculation(a)

print(a)        # input
print(output)   # output
```

### EDIT

This is the edit for what you requested (Case where time instances are not contiguous). Just replace the `for` loop with this one:

```
  for (i in c(1:nrow(a))){
    if(i>1){
      if (upperright[i]) upperrightquadrant <- upperrightquadrant + a[i, 1] - a[i-1, 1]
      if (upperleft[i]) upperleftquadrant <- upperleftquadrant + a[i, 1] - a[i-1, 1]
      if (lowerright[i]) lowerrightquadrant <- lowerrightquadrant + a[i, 1] - a[i-1, 1]
      if (lowerleft[i]) lowerleftquadrant <- lowerleftquadrant + a[i, 1] - a[i-1, 1]
    } else {
      if (upperright[i]) upperrightquadrant <- upperrightquadrant + a[i, 1]
      if (upperleft[i]) upperleftquadrant <- upperleftquadrant + a[i, 1]
      if (lowerright[i]) lowerrightquadrant <- lowerrightquadrant + a[i, 1]
      if (lowerleft[i]) lowerleftquadrant <- lowerleftquadrant + a[i, 1]
    }
  }
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. I have a last question on the corrected programm:                      You said:"Problem with sum((a[i,1]-a[i-1,1])) at i==1, i-1 equals 0. If you are only counting, incrementing the count by 1 should be sufficient."                                          I just made an easy matrix for the start but I actually wanted to have in the "time" column of matrix "a" a cumulative increasing time as here but in uneven steps eg. 1,3,7,8,,10...I can´t come up with the way to avoid the problem with the initial i.

Comment: @chiser - could you post the correct result so I can see if I'm understanding the question correctly?

Comment: @chiser, OK I think I understand your problem now. You were right in your approach. Just add a check for index `i==1` in the corrected program before your `sum((a[i,1]-a[i-1,1]))` statements and handle the situation. Plus don't you think the `sum` function is unnecessary here.

Comment: @chiser, I have added the needed modification according to your request. See if this is what you wanted.